# How to configure single app on heroku in different environments?

Tags: heroku, deployment

I have an app running at myapp.herokuapps.com, however I created a pipeline for it and by default it appeared on production. using heroku UI i moved the app to development. I understood that, only one app is possible at a time in one environment. If so, how can I run one app in multiple environments like development and staging and production? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [heroku fork](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fork-app) to clone your app.
Then assign the cloned app to the [heroku pipelines](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pipelines) phase that you require.

Comment: would that cloned app mapped to a different url or same url ? I am worried about this cause my app has a mongo addon. I dont want to get charged for another instance of mongo as its gets charged per app basis.

Comment: The cloned app will have a separate URL.
It will also consume separate instances of any add-ons.
After cloning, you can modify the plans used for any add-ons separately in each app. So, for example, in your Development/Staging pipeline phases app you could use free plans of add-ons, whereas you could use paid plans of add-ons (if necessary) in your production pipeline phase app.